# Execute and get the output from a MIPS file (Mars environment) in Java

Tags: java, io, mips, execution, mars-simulator

I have a java code that creates some MIPS code and puts into a file (say output.asm). I was wondering if there is a way that I can execute this MIPS file and get whatever it prints on the console in my java code?

Note: I am using Mars 4.5

Answer (score 0):

The command for running mars on command line without opening it is:

```
java -jar Mars4_5.jar output.asm
```